# "hello world" program from GTK home page seg faults

Tags: c, linux, gtk, x86-64

As you can see I am the newest you can be to gtk. I tried just running the hello world from the gtk homepage but it just segmentation faults. I have no idea why, if anyone can help, thanks in advance!!

```c
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void on_activate (GtkApplication *app) {
  // Create a new window
  GtkWidget *window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  // Create a new button
  GtkWidget *button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Hello, World!");
  // When the button is clicked, close the window passed as an argument
  g_signal_connect_swapped (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (gtk_window_close), window);
  gtk_window_set_child (GTK_WINDOW (window), button);
  gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW (window));
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  // Create a new application
  GtkApplication *app = gtk_application_new ("com.example.GtkApplication", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (on_activate), NULL);
  return g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
}
```

This is the program from the [gtk.org](https://gtk.org) homepage. it seg faults when i run it.

gdb backtrace

```
#0  0x00007ffff72e906c in type_node_check_conformities_UorL
    (node=0x55555557ca10, iface_node=iface_node@entry=0x5557a540, support_interfaces=support_interfaces@entry=1, support_prerequisites=support_prerequisites@entry=0, have_lock=have_lock@entry=0) at ../glib/gobject/gtype.c:3519
#1  0x00007ffff72eb2ca in type_node_conforms_to_U (support_prerequisites=0, support_interfaces=1, iface_node=0x5557a540, node=<optimized out>) at ../glib/gobject/gtype.c:3564
#2  g_type_check_instance_cast (type_instance=0x5555555840e0, iface_type=<optimized out>) at ../glib/gobject/gtype.c:4128
#3  0x00005555555552d3 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffde18) at src/main.c:19
```

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff72e906c in type_node_check_conformities_UorL (node=0x55555557ca10, iface_node=iface_node@entry=0x5557a540, support_interfaces=support_interfaces@entry=1, support_prerequisites=support_prerequisites@entry=0, have_lock=have_lock@entry=0) at ../glib/gobject/gtype.c:3519
3519          NODE_IS_ANCESTOR (iface_node, node))
```

Comment: While line is line 19?

Comment: `return g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);`

Comment: You're running this in a session with an X server running, right?  So you can start other GUI programs like `xterm` or `xev` and have them open a window.  I don't know GTK, but it doesn't look like there's a lot of error checking of return values.

Comment: yup, i can start both xterm and xev. xorg is also running

Comment: How do you compile it?

Comment: `cc $(pkg-config --cflags gtk4) -o out/main src/main.c $(pkg-config --libs gtk4)`

Comment: Can't reproduce, the program runs just fine for me...

Answer (score 1):

From the [gtk documentation](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/method.Window.close.html), the declaration of `gtk_window_close` function is

```c
void
gtk_window_close (
  GtkWindow* window
)
```

the `window` variable is declared as GtkWidget, you need to cast the `window` variable using `GTK_WINDOW`

```c
g_signal_connect_swapped (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (gtk_window_close), GTK_WINDOW (window));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, though it doesn't seem to solve the issue!